# Why does my fscanf not read?

Tags: c, debugging, scanf

I have to write a program that finds a path of maximum value in a triangular maze of integer numbers.

- This program should calculate the highest sum of numbers passed on a route that starts at the top and ends somewhere on the base.
- Each step can go either diagonally down to the left or diagonally down to the right.
- The number of rows in the triangle is > 1 but <= 100.
- The numbers in the triangle, all integers, are between 0 and 99.

I have a problem with the `fscanf` function. It doesn't read for some reason. I would highly appreciate any help or advise as this project is due ASAP.

Here is an example of a maze:

> 30
>
> 47 1
>
> 35 65 21
>
> 0 74 94 58
>
> 71 29 34 28 60
>
> 97 6 29 19 26 68
>
> 37 1 48 98 57 89 64
>
> 60 38 33 23 49 57 19 50
>
> 4 83 52 47 84 60 16 56 90
>
> 19 59 6 10 97 47 96 93 59 50

And this is what I've got so far:

```
/#include <stdio.h>
/#include <stdlib.h>
/#define MAX 100

void read    (int maze [][MAX]);
int findPath (int maze[][MAX], int map[][MAX], int size);
void print   (int map [][MAX]);

int main()
{
    int maze [][MAX] = {};
    int map  [][MAX] = {};

    int sum = 0;
    int size = MAX;

    read     (maze);
    findPath (maze, map,size);
    print    (map);

    return;
}

void read (int maze[][MAX])
{
    FILE * mazeFile;
    int num, r, c, count;

    if ((mazeFile = fopen ("t4.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf ("Error opening a file\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while (mazeFile != EOF)
        {        
            fscanf (mazeFile, "%d", &maze[r][c]);

            for (r = 0; r < 100 ; r++)
            {
                count = r + 1;
                for (c = 0; c <= count; c++)
                {
                    printf ("(%d, %d) = %d\n",r, c, maze[r][c]);
                }
            }
            fclose (mazeFile);
            return;
        }
    }
}

int findPath (int maze[][MAX], int map[][MAX], int size)
{
    int sum [MAX][MAX] = {0};
    int row, col, maxNum;

    for(row=(size-1); row >= 1; --row)
    {
        for (col-row;col>=1;--col)
        {
            maxNum = (sum[row+1][col] > sum [row+1][col+1] ? col : col + 1);
            sum[row][col]= maze[row][col] + sum [row+1][maxNum];

            map[row][col] = maxNum;
        }
    }  
    return sum [0][0];
}

void print (int map [][MAX])
{
    printf ("(%d, %d) = ", map[0][0], map[0][1]);
    return;
}
```

Comment: [This shouldn't even compile](http://ideone.com/OSwpjl).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well :-) There are a lot of issues but the one that you ask about is reading the file so I will just address that for now:

#### Some Corrections

- First do NOT use `read`, `write`, as they are standard library functions you will run into lots of issues;
- Do not use void as a return type for functions, use int and return 0 on success and negative
  numbers for failure (it's conventional) and helps you write code that catches errors
- Do use comments to describe your function
- Tabs are good, at least 4 spaces ( I am a kernel programmer so I like 8-space tabs)
  they help when you are sleepy at 2:30AM and trying to figure out answers
- ALL statements inside a function should be tabbed in and NOT line up with the { }
- A good convention is to use opening { on newline only for function body and for the rest
  like **if**, **for**, **while** etc the { should be on the same line as the statement and closing } should line up with the first letter of the statement.
- DO NOT put too many white spaces between each statement. It makes code less readable.

### Example of good approach

Here is an example of how to code reading the file properly.

### Step 1:

create a simple function that just reads the contents and dumps it back out so that you know your READING is fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/** 
 * @function: read_maze
 * @desc: Reads a maze file and dumps it to stdout, 
 * @return: Returns 0 on success, -1 on failure
 *
 */

int read_maze(const char *filename) 
{
     FILE *fp;
     int entry;

     fp = fopen(filename, "r");
     if ( !fp ) {
          perror(filename); /* prints system error related to
                             * the problem reading mazefile 
                             */
          return -1;
     }

     while(!feof(fp)) {
          if (fscanf(fp, "%d", &entry) == 1) { 
              printf ("%d\n", entry);
          }
     }

     return 0;
}

int main()
{
     if(read_maze("t4.txt")) {
          return -1;
     }

     return 0;
}
```

### Step 2:

Create a triangular maze array that makes sense:

Okay so now that we know that we can read a file properly let's try and put it into a structure that makes sense.

We know that we have a bunch of rows (100), 1st row has 1 column, 2nd row has 2, 3rd row 3, and so on...

In other words each row has the same number of columns as its cardinality (index+1);

So is it something like the following?

```
int row0[1];
int row1[2];
int row2[3];
   .
   .
   .
int row99[100];
```

That's kinda ugly and not really programmatic; it would be nice to do this automatically;
Well we know that the fixed number is the number of rows and the dynamic allocation is associated to the index. So let's make an array of pointers to integers; and then each member of this array can be a dynamically allocated memory block just as big as the cardinality of the member. (Mouthful hehe)

```
#define MAXROWS 100

int *row[MAXROWS];
```

NOTE: that conceptually MAXROWS actually corresponds to the hardcoded 0-99 we stuck in front the word `row` and NOT the declaration piece of array size in brackets.  So for `int row55[56];` this is about declaring the 55; the 56 declaration will come from a malloc later;

Now we know that a pointer to a data type is exactly that, a pointer that POINT to memory blocks for our data (essentially acting as an array) in other words let's allocate the appropriate columns for each row:

```
 /* starting from beginning */

 #define MAXROWS 100

 int *rows[MAXROWS];

 int init_triangular_array() 
 {
     int k;
     memset(rows, 0, sizeof(int *)*MAXROWS); /* make the rows array all zeros */
     for (k = 0; k < MAXROWS; k++) {
         rows[k] = (int *)calloc(k+1, sizeof(int)); /* cardinality */
         if( rows[k] == NULL ) {
              fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate memory, quoting\n");
              exit(-1); /* just kill the program */
         }
     }
 }
```

Now that we have a function to  initialize the array ... let's also create a function to free the array when we are done with it; as that's just good coding practice.

```
 void free_triangular_array()
 {
     int k;
     for (k = 0; k  < MAXROWS; k++ ) {
         if ( rows[k] ) 
              free(rows[k]);
     }
 }
```

And now lets write a function to fill it up from our file:

```
 int fill_triangular_array(const char *filename)
 {

       FILE *fp = fopen(...);
       int row = 0, col = 0;

       while(!feof(fp)) {
             for (col = 0; col <= row_number; col++ ) {
                   // read an entry as above 
                   rows[row][col] = entry; 
             }
       }
 }
```

You get to fill in the missing bits.

and once you've done that now to use it all

```
 int main() 
 {

         init_triangular_array();
         fill_triangular_array();
         /* do something with the array */
         free_triangular_array();

 }
```

Comment: Thank you for corrections. I'm just a beginner in programming, so those notes would help a lot. Yes, we did malloc and calloc. P.S The function that you wrote runs like a champ ;)

Comment: Okay then the way to read the triangular maze in is to use malloc or calloc... I can give you a hint on that too.  Do you see the point about tabs and white space? I hope my code feels readable to you

Comment: Yes, the file is much easier to read. But I'm in intro C class, and some parts of the code is clearly new for me or not understandable. And is it C or C++?

Comment: This is pure C nothing C++ here.

Comment: I'm not really sure why I need malloc for this task? Isn't it is simpler the way I tried to do?

Comment: Your way won't work; you'll run into a crashing program; yes you do need calloc for this

Comment: Thank you VERY much! It's quiet a chunk of information. I'm going to get some sleep and process it in the morning. Again, thanks a lot! Will reply ASAP with what it turned into